# How to switch configuration while debugging .Net core 2.x app?

Tags: c#, configuration, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, appsettings

Have been looking for the right way to add configurations to my dot net core 2.0 web API.

Until now what I have done is:

1. Added appsetteings.Development.json, appsetteings.Production.json
2. In program.cs:

   ```
   public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
   {
       return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
           .UseStartup<Startup>()
           .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
           {
               var env = hostContext.HostingEnvironment;
               config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                   .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
           })
           .Build();
   }
   ```
3. In startup.cs

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       services.AddMvc();
       services.Configure<dynamic>(Configuration);
   }
   ```

The issue is whenever I debug my code it always takes settings from `appsettings.Development.json`.

I also found that the `hostContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName` always comes as development regardless of which environment I pick to debug in.

Comment: I suggest you edit your title (make it a How To question) before this question is closed as off topic. [*Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) We can add reference links to answers, but you shouldn't request them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a setting with the project properties that is causing the Development environment setting to be used during debug.

Open Project properties
Navigate to the Debug page
In the Environment Variables section you will see:

ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT | Development

[image]

If you remove this flag and debug you app it should be running without the Development settings.

The official documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was very helpful.

Comment: What if it's a Console app?